# Inconsistency between maxbytes & bytes. Oracle

Tags: oracle, disk-space, tablespaces

Query:

```
Select ROUND (SUM (d.bytes) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)) AS size1, 
ROUND (SUM (d.maxbytes) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)) AS size2
From dba_data_files d where tablespace_name = 'TABLESPACE_NAME'
```

Output:

> size1: 70, size2: 64

As you can see the max bytes allowed for the data files for a particular table-space is only 64GB however it has somehow extended to 70GB!!

Scenario: At a given point the table-space got completely filled (64GB) and I saw 100% used in one of my routine checks. So I went ahead and temporarily truncated some unwanted tables to free up some space. I didn't encounter the `cannot extend error` anywhere in any of my processes (although it might have occurred) but what bugs me is that the total size of the table-space just increased from 64GB(max) where it should have stopped to 70(gb).

Please advise how it could have happened or any option I have missed !! and where is the extra 6 GB being stored.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

**Output of :**

```
select bytes,maxbytes,autoextensible 
  from dba_data_files
 where tablespace_name = 'TABLESPACE_NAME';

15728640000 4294967296  YES

30303846400 32212254720 YES

28626124800 32212254720 YES
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MAXBYTES` is 0 for datafiles that are not autoextensible, but `BYTES` is greater than 0. Use this:

```
Select ROUND (SUM (d.bytes) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)) AS size1, 
ROUND (SUM (decode(d.maxbytes, 0, d.bytes, d.maxbytes)) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)) AS size2
From dba_data_files d where tablespace_name = 'TABLESPACE_NAME';
```

But it is possible to manually resize a datafile above `maxbytes`.

```
SQL> select file_id, bytes, maxbytes from dba_data_files;

   FILE_ID      BYTES   MAXBYTES
---------- ---------- ----------
         1  954204160 3.4360E+10
         3 1142947840 3.4360E+10
         5  608174080 3.4360E+10
         7    5242880   10485760

SQL> alter database datafile 7 resize 20M;

Database altered.

SQL> select file_id, bytes, maxbytes from dba_data_files;

   FILE_ID      BYTES   MAXBYTES
---------- ---------- ----------
         1  954204160 3.4360E+10
         3 1142947840 3.4360E+10
         5  608174080 3.4360E+10
         7   20971520   10485760
```

I updated the query:

```
Select ROUND (SUM (d.bytes) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)) AS size1, 
ROUND (SUM (greates(d.bytes, d.maxbytes)) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)) AS size2
From dba_data_files d where tablespace_name = 'TABLESPACE_NAME';
```

Comment: Hi, actually I only have 3 data-files for that table-space & all of them are auto-extensible. I still tried your query to get the same result.

Comment: @pOrinG Then post the result of `select bytes, maxbytes, autoextensible from dba_data_files where tablespace_name = 'TABLESPACE_NAME';`.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question to add the output.

Comment: @pOrinG Ok, I updated my answer.

Comment: Hi, but that's the thing. No one manually resized it. I am 100% sure of it. The database is managed by me, as in I am not the dba but I hold all the passwords & connections and no-one else can login let alone resize without my presence. Hence my dilemma. Please check the scenario I mentioned in the question.

Comment: I go through the used space every week and there was nothing fishy the previous week and suddenly when it became 100% the next week it auto extended beyond max.